# Is it bad practice to name relational database tables using a period separated namespace

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have noticed that most naming conventions in relational database systems throughout my career have always been in the format of app1_feature1_person, using an underscore as word separator. The problem I have with this goes back to my personal relationship with underscore on coding, its a shift key combination making it always more effort to type when cranking code out and it does not match my namespace strategy in java where I'd like to change the table name above to com.mycompany.app1.feature1.Person.

I'm wondering if there any valid reasons why the common naming convention is based on an underscore and if adding a period delimitated namespace in my table name is bad design practice. (Using MySql)

Comment: If I inherited this schema, I'd have some choice words for my predecessor.

Comment: @Strawberry can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Your choice is between using underscores (`app1_feature1_person`) or using periods and quoting the identifier (`"app1.feature1.person"`). Quoting is a pain in the neck and very error prone, so I would stay with underscores.

Comment: Not without contravening SO rules

Comment: Dots in java are not parts of names. We can reasonably say dots are used in SQL the same way they are used in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Put shortly, the period is already the delimiter between schema, table and column name. The period is for me the worst possible character you could use in a table name. And you'd always have the hazzle of having to quote the table name with backticks.

Comment: That is a good point, what do you think about using a hyphen (-) just anything to get rid of the underscore.

Comment: A hyphen would also have to be quoted, which is a no-go for me. But if you feel like it, go for it. That aside I'm actually wondering about your table names. I've never come across a database where such cryptic names were necessary. Different apps usually use different schemas. And if you still have cryptic names, you could also question if your schema is properly normalized.

Comment: @duncankrebs a hyphen is, if anything, worse . It has the potential to cause catastrophic error, without even being aware of it!

Comment: Strawberry actually has a good point. Didn't think of that. But for that to happen you would have to have a column `a` and `b` when you forget to quote the column `a-b`.

Comment: Prior comments have addressed the issues with using '.' in your table names. Given a name like 'app1_feature1_person' I'd like to ask would you have be likely to have another table named 'app2_feature1_person' with the same schema as the first table, but with different data? If such tables are an attempt to provide some kind of multi-tenant solution, I'd suggest creating a separate 'database schema' for each tenants tables. Each tenants 'database' can be configured, located, backed up, managed, and tuned independent of the others.

Comment: @Tom Drake , thanks for the advice, i think you have two good points separate my schemas despite being a single OSGI application with many plugins that have different features, this will make life easier, second, get my naming strategy more normalized and lastly deal with using an underscore.

Comment: @Tom Drake you are totally right, the problem is I'm in a early alpha stage of a pretty complex automated trading system with multiple OSGI plugins that all offer new features and my thinking was to just start with one db for now prefix table names with feature and then break into different schemas when needed, but should probably just do that now. Thanks Again